# How can I change the colors of a stepper for iOS and Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code uses a stepper which looks like this:

[image: Stepper control]

How can I change the color Blue to Red for the iOS and Android versions of the stepper by setting the new color in XAML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using [Effects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/passing-parameters/attached-properties/).

## Code

I've created a sample app here: https://github.com/brminnick/CustomStepper

### Consuming the Effects in XAML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="CustomStepper.StepperPage"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomStepper">
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Stepper
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            local:StepperColorEffect.Color="Red"/>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

### Stepper Color Effect

```cs
using System.Linq;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CustomStepper
{
    public static class StepperColorEffect
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.CreateAttached(nameof(Color),
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(Stepper),
                Color.Gray,
                propertyChanged: OnStepperColorChanged);

        public static Color GetColor(BindableObject view) => (Color)view.GetValue(ColorProperty);

        public static void SetColor(BindableObject view, Color value) => view.SetValue(ColorProperty, value);

        static void OnStepperColorChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue) => UpdateEffect(bindable);

        static void UpdateEffect(BindableObject bindable)
        {
            var stepper = (Stepper)bindable:
            RemoveEffect(stepper);
            stepper.Effects.Add(new StepperColorRoutingEffect());
        }

        static void RemoveEffect(Stepper entry)
        {
            var effectToRemoveList = entry.Effects.OfType<StepperColorRoutingEffect>();

            foreach (var entryReturnTypeEffect in effectToRemoveList)
                entry.Effects.Remove(entryReturnTypeEffect);
        }
    }

    class StepperColorRoutingEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public StepperColorRoutingEffect() : base("CustomStepper.StepperColorEffect")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

### iOS PlatformEffect

```cs
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using CustomStepper.iOS;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("CustomStepper")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(StepperColorEffect), nameof(StepperColorEffect))]
namespace CustomStepper.iOS
{
    public class StepperColorEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            if (Element is Stepper element && Control is UIStepper control)
            {
                control.TintColor = CustomStepper.StepperColorEffect.GetColor(element).ToUIColor();
                control.SetIncrementImage(Control.GetIncrementImage(UIControlState.Normal), UIControlState.Normal);
                control.SetDecrementImage(Control.GetDecrementImage(UIControlState.Normal), UIControlState.Normal);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            if (Element is Stepper element && Control is UIStepper control)
            {
                control.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
                control.SetIncrementImage(Control.GetIncrementImage(UIControlState.Normal), UIControlState.Normal);
                control.SetDecrementImage(Control.GetDecrementImage(UIControlState.Normal), UIControlState.Normal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Android PlatformEffect

```cs
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using CustomStepper.Droid;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("CustomStepper")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(StepperColorEffect), nameof(StepperColorEffect))]
namespace CustomStepper.Droid
{
    public class StepperColorEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            if (Element is Stepper element && Control is LinearLayout control)
            {
                control.GetChildAt(0).Background.SetColorFilter(CustomStepper.StepperColorEffect.GetColor(element).ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
                control.GetChildAt(1).Background.SetColorFilter(CustomStepper.StepperColorEffect.GetColor(element).ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            if (Element is Stepper element && Control is LinearLayout control)
            {
                control.GetChildAt(0).Background.SetColorFilter(Xamarin.Forms.Color.Gray.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
                control.GetChildAt(1).Background.SetColorFilter(Xamarin.Forms.Color.Gray.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Screenshots

### Android

[image]

### iOS

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  Just one more thing as outlined in the question. Can you make it so I can add something like Color="Red" or Color="Black" to the XAML for a custom stepper.  I would like not to hard code the color into the renderer.

Comment: Hey @Alan2! I've updated the answer to use Effects. Please don't edit and change your question in the future, because it is a big waste of time for fellow developers who are trying to answer your question. I spent over an hour solving your original question. Then you edited the original question and I spent another 45 minutes solving your second question. Next time, please open a second question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry but I think you maybe didn't notice that the need to change in XAML  was mentioned in the text of the bounty.  Here's what it says: "where I can add something like Color="Red" or Color="Black" to the XAML".   What I was hoping for was something like  <local:Stepper Color="Red"..  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> How can I change the colors of a stepper for iOS and Android?

In your `Xamarin.Android` project, you could create a custom vector drawable and use it as a background to achieve the same appearance as the picture you have post above.

Place the `button_selector.xml` and `button_border.xml` file in your Android `Resources\drawable` folder:

#### button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_border"/>
</selector>
```

#### button_border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >

  <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  <stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

In your `ExtStepperRenderer`:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    MyStepper s = Element as MyStepper;

    if (Control != null)
    {
        var button = Control.GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.Button;
        button.SetTextColor(s.MyColor.ToAndroid());
        button.SetBackground(ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.button_selector, null));
        button.Background.SetColorFilter(s.MyColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);

        var button2 = Control.GetChildAt(1) as Android.Widget.Button;
        button2.SetTextColor(s.MyColor.ToAndroid());
        button2.SetBackground(ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.button_selector, null));
        button2.Background.SetColorFilter(s.MyColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
    }
}
```

Effect on Android device:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution that also refer from @Alan2's answer.

Xamarin.Forms

```
    public class StepperExtend : Stepper
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Color),
            typeof(Color),
            typeof(StepperExtend),
            Color.Default);

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Xamarin.Android

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(StepperExtend), typeof(StepperExtendRenderer))]
```

namespace HydroUkPoc.Frontend.Forms.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class StepperExtendRenderer : StepperRenderer
    {
        StepperExtend FormElement
        {
            get { return Element as StepperExtend; }
        }

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            UpdateColor();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == StepperExtend.ColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateColor();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateColor()
    {
        Control.GetChildAt(0).Background.SetColorFilter(FormElement.Color.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
        Control.GetChildAt(1).Background.SetColorFilter(FormElement.Color.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
    }
}
```

}

Xamarin.iOS

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(StepperExtend), typeof(StepperExtendRenderer))]
```

namespace HydroUkPoc.Frontend.Forms.iOS.Renderer
{
    public class StepperExtendRenderer : StepperRenderer
    {
        StepperExtend FormElement
        {
            get { return Element as StepperExtend; }
        }

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            UpdateColor();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == StepperExtend.ColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateColor();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateColor()
    {
        Control.TintColor = FormElement.Color.ToUIColor();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom renderer. Looking at the source code, the native control for the Stepper on [iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/74cb5c4a97dcb123eb471f6b1dffa1267d0305aa/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/StepperRenderer.cs) is `UIStepper`, and on [Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e32f96e97ac4b3a8d067d502c31ad67dd9d7d54d/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/StepperRenderer.cs) it is actually a horizontal `LinearLayout` with two buttons. So for Android, the custom renderer should update the background color of the buttons, and on iOS, they appear to be icons, so try changing the `TintColor` of the `UIStepper`.

Answer (score -2):

I came up with a simple solution.

Common File:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese
{
    public class ExtStepper : Stepper
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty ColorProperty =
   BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Color),
       typeof(Color), typeof(ExtStepper),
       Color.Default);

        public Color StepperColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
        }

    }
}
```

iOS

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Japanese;
using Japanese.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtStepper), typeof(ExtStepperRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.iOS
{
    public class ExtStepperRenderer : StepperRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            ExtStepper s = Element as ExtStepper;

            if (Control != null)
                Control.TintColor = s.StepperColor.ToUIColor();

        }
    }
}
```

Andoid

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Japanese;
using Japanese.Droid;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtStepper), typeof(ExtStepperRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.Droid
{
    public class ExtStepperRenderer : StepperRenderer
    {
        public ExtStepperRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            ExtStepper s = Element as ExtStepper;

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.GetChildAt(0).Background.SetColorFilter(s.StepperColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
                Control.GetChildAt(1).Background.SetColorFilter(s.StepperColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<local:ExtStepper StepperColor="Red" x:Name="rptStepper
```

Comment: Hey @Alan2! This will work if you are assigning the Color once. If you try to update the Color a second time or bind it to the ViewModel, the Stepper Color won't update.