# C# Xamarin: How to center button text in android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my PCL I am using Steppers which I changed the colors. In my Android I changed the Stepper's button size like the following:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
{
   base.OnElementChanged(e);
   ExtStepper s = Element as ExtStepper;

   if (Control != null)
   {
      var downBtn = Control.GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.Button;
      downBtn.SetMinHeight(0);
      downBtn.SetMinimumHeight(0);
      downBtn.SetHeight(80);
      downBtn.SetMinWidth(0);
      downBtn.SetMinimumWidth(0);
      downBtn.SetWidth(150);

      var upBtn = Control.GetChildAt(1) as Android.Widget.Button;
      upBtn.SetMinHeight(0);
      upBtn.SetMinimumHeight(0);
      upBtn.SetHeight(80);
      upBtn.SetMinWidth(0);
      upBtn.SetMinimumWidth(0);
      upBtn.SetWidth(150);
    }
}
```

This works like I wanted it to work but the problem is the `-` and `+` text are no longer visible as shown in the image below.

[image]

I have tried the following code to no avail.

```
downBtn.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
downBtn.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
downBtn.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;
downBtn.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
```

Anyone has suggestions on how this should be done?

EDIT:

Also, as seen in the image, my Stepper buttons no longer have space in between. How should I solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48591783/3701787

Comment: @ZiyadGodil this doesn't answer my question. The `-` and `+` text are there but they are not showing due to the height problem. If I change the height say 100 (which I don't want) then the text would show. Hence the question, how to center the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This works like I wanted it to work but the problem is the - and + text are no longer visible as shown in the image below.

You need to set clear/set the button's inner paddings:

```
 if (Control != null)
 {
      var downBtn = Control.GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.Button;
      downBtn.SetMinHeight(0);
      downBtn.SetMinimumHeight(0);
      downBtn.SetHeight(40);
      downBtn.SetMinWidth(0);
      downBtn.SetMinimumWidth(0);
      downBtn.SetWidth(150);
      //clear the padding to show the font
      downBtn.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);


      var upBtn = Control.GetChildAt(1) as Android.Widget.Button;
      upBtn.SetMinHeight(0);
      upBtn.SetMinimumHeight(0);
      upBtn.SetHeight(40);
      upBtn.SetMinWidth(0);
      upBtn.SetMinimumWidth(0);
      upBtn.SetWidth(150);
      //clear the padding to show the font
      upBtn.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
```